# Inter-arrival time distribution of a Poisson process

Tags: poisson-process

I'm actually looking at a rigorous way to prove that if $\{N_t\}_{t\geq 0}$is a Poisson process of rate $\lambda >0$, then the inter-arrival times $(H_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are independently and identically distributed exponential random variable with rate parameter $\lambda$.

Note that for this I use the two definitions of Poisson process that does not use the above statement as a definition that is (the equivalence between the two definition is already proved):

**Def 1:**
A Poisson process $\{N_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ of rate $\lambda >0$ is a stochastic process with values in $\mathbb{N}$ satisfying:

1. $N_0=0$ a.s
2. The increments are independent, that is given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq t_0<\dots<t_n$ $N_{t_0}, N_{t_1}-N_{t_0},\dots,N_{t_{n-1}}-N_{t_n}$ are independent.
3. $P(N_t-N_s=k)=P(N_{t-s}=k), t\geq s$
4. $P(N_{t+\delta}-N_t=1)=\lambda\delta+o(\delta)$
5. $P(N_{t+\delta}-N_t \geq 2)=o(\delta)$

**Def 2:**
A Poisson process $\{N_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ of rate $\lambda >0$ is a stochastic process with values in $\mathbb{N}$ satisfying:

1. $N_0=0$ a.s
2. The increments are independent, that is given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0\leq t_0<\dots<t_n$ $N_{t_0}, N_{t_1}-N_{t_0},\dots,N_{t_{n-1}}-N_{t_n}$ are independent.
3. $P(N_t-N_s=k)=P(N_{t-s}=k), t\geq s$
4. $N_t \sim Poi(\lambda t)$

What I want to avoid is what seems to be the classic proof that consider object like $P(H_2>t|H_1=t_1)$ which has no sense for me as $H_1$ is continuous ( namely exponential) and $H_2$ could be (at this step) any type of random variable. (and hence $P(H_1=t)=0 \forall t$)

Thank's by advance to the one that will propose me a good proof for this.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is with conditioning on $H_1 = t_1$. The fact that $H_1$ is continuous only means that it can take on any positive real value. Once it is realized/observed it will still have to take _some_ value. If you are not willing to condition on continuous random variables, there will be many things in probability that you won't be able to do.

Comment: Maybe my background is too light but my issue is just that $P(H_1=t)=0$ so I can't use the classic formula of conditioned probability by an event.

Comment: The details of the proof will critically depend on the definition you are using, so it would be nice if you can fix one such version.

Comment: Okay I'll add it to the initial post right now. Thanks for answering.

Comment: You can still condition on the event $H_1 = t$. If you condition on it, it has already happened. You can easily simulate from exponential distributions, and any such simulation will give you specific real values, each of which technically has zero probability to appear. If you need to do a Bayes-like computation, relax $H_1 = t$ to $H_1 \in\left[t,t+dt\right]$ and take $dt \to 0$. You will see that $dt$ cancels out from the numerator and denominator, so there is no issue of dividing by zero.

Comment: for me it's not clear why the quantity you mentioned is converging that is why $\lim_{dt \rightarrow 0}P(H_2>t|H_1\in[t,t+dt])=\lim_{dt \rightarrow 0} \frac{P(H_2>t,H_1\in[t,t+dt])}{P(H_1\in[t,t+dt])}$ exist

Comment: Both the numerator and denominator look like something times $dt$, because $P\left(X \in \left[t,t+dt\right]\right)$ behaves like the density of $X$, evaluated at $t$, multiplied by $dt$. Then, $dt$ cancels out of the numerator and denominator.

Comment: I see why this is bounded but not really why there is convergence, maybe can you formalise it ?

Comment: $dt$ cancels out of the numerator and denominator, so the ratio no longer depends on it at all. It is a trivial "limit."

Comment: I'm sorry but when it's clear why the denominator is like $f(t)\times dt$, I don't see why the numerator is like $a \times dt$, maybe it's trivial but if it's the case maybe you can precise it in only a few equations ? The existence of the limit is something unclear for me at this time but I'll really happy to see a simple and precise explanation if you're agree to take the time to do so. Best

Answer (score 3):

We will assume that $N$ has right-continuous sample paths. Define the firth arrival time $T_1$ by

$$ T_1 = \inf \{ t \geq 0 : N_t \geq 1 \}. $$

By the right-continuity, this implies that $N_{T_1} = 1$. Then we will prove the following claim, which is a special case of the strong Markov property:

> **Claim.** Define a new stochastic process $\tilde{N} = ( \tilde{N}_t )_{t\geq 0}$ by
> $$ \tilde{N}_t = N_{T_1 + t} - N_{T_1} = N_{T_1 + t} - 1. $$
> Then we have the following:
>
> 1. $T_1$ and $\tilde{N}$ are independent.
> 2. $\tilde{N}$ is a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$.
> 3. $T_1$ is an exponential random variable of rate $\lambda$.

*Proof.* Fix $0 < t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n$. Also, let $\delta > 0$ be sufficiently small so that $0 < t_0 - \delta$ and $t_{i-1}+\delta < t_i-\delta$ holds for all $i = 1, \dots, n$.

Now, for any parameters $s, s_1, \dots, s_n \geq 0$, we consider

$$ Y = sT_1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} s_i (\tilde{N}_{t_i} - \tilde{N}_{t_{i-1}}). $$

Then, conditioned on $\{T_1 \in ((k-1)\delta, k\delta] \}$, we have

$$ Y \geq s (k-1)\delta + \sum_{i=1}^{n} s_i (N_{(k-1)\delta + t_i} - N_{k\delta + t_{i-1}}) $$

and so,

$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{-Y}]
\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[ \exp\left\{ - s (k-1)\delta - \sum_{i=1}^{n} s_i (N_{(k-1)\delta + t_i} - N_{k\delta + t_{i-1}}) \right\} \mathbf{1}_{\{T_1 \in ((k-1)\delta, k\delta]  \}} \right]. \tag{1} $$

By noting that $\{T_1 \in ((k-1)\delta, k\delta] \} = \{ N_{(k-1)\delta} = 0 \text{ and } N_{k\delta} \geq 1 \} $, all of

$$ \mathbf{1}_{\{T_1 \in ((k-1)\delta, k\delta]  \}}, \quad N_{(k-1)\delta + t_1} - N_{k\delta + t_{0}}, \quad \dots, \quad N_{(k-1)\delta + t_n} - N_{k\delta + t_{n-1}} $$

are independent, and hence the bound $\text{(1)}$ reduces to

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[e^{-Y}]
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-s(k-1)\delta} \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{-s_i (N_{(k-1)\delta + t_i} - N_{k\delta + t_{i-1}})} \right] \right) \mathbb{P} \left( T_1 \in ((k-1)\delta, k\delta] \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-s(k-1)\delta} \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} e^{-\lambda(t_i - t_{i-1} - \delta) (1 - e^{-s_i}) } \right) e^{-\lambda (k-1)\delta} (1 - e^{-\lambda \delta}) \\
&= \frac{1 - e^{-\lambda \delta}}{1 - e^{-(s+\lambda)\delta}} \prod_{i=1}^{n} e^{-\lambda(t_i - t_{i-1} - \delta) (1 - e^{-s_i}) }. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

As $\delta \to 0^+$, the bound $\text{(2)}$ converges to

$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{-Y}] \leq \frac{\lambda}{s+\lambda} \prod_{i=1}^{n} e^{-\lambda(t_i - t_{i-1}) (1 - e^{-s_i}) }. \tag{3} $$

By a similar computation applied to

$$ Y \leq s k\delta + \sum_{i=1}^{n} s_i (N_{k\delta + t_i} - N_{(k-1)\delta + t_{i-1}}), $$

we can also obtain the reverse direction of $\text{(3)}$. So it follows that

$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{-Y}] = \frac{\lambda}{s+\lambda} \prod_{i=1}^{n} e^{-\lambda(t_i - t_{i-1}) (1 - e^{-s_i}) } \tag{4} $$

holds for any choices of parameters $s, s_1, \dots, s_n \geq 0$. However, since the multidimensional Laplace transform uniquely determines the law of a given random vector, this proves that:

1. $ T_1$, $\tilde{N}_{t_1} - \tilde{N}_{t_{0}}$, $\ldots$, $\tilde{N}_{t_n} - \tilde{N}_{t_{n-1}} $ are mutually independent,
2. $\tilde{N}_{t_i} - \tilde{N}_{t_{i-1}} \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda(t_i - t_{i-1}))$ for each $i = 1, \dots, n$, and
3. $T_1 \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$.

Therefore the desired claim follows. $\square$

Now repeatedly applying this claim shows that inter-arrival times are independent exponential random variables of rate $\lambda$ as desired.

Comment: Thank's for your contribution, now it clear ! Just a question, when you repeat you argument you will show that $T_1,T_2$ and the new (poisson) process will be independent right ?

Comment: What I understand is that you prove that $\tilde{\tilde{N}}$ and $T_2$ have the good proprieties and after that you prove that $T_1$ is independent with $T_2$ and $\tilde{\tilde{N}}$ as they are function of random variable which are independent with $T_1$. Is that right ?

Comment: @ArthurSerres, You are correct. The lemma tells that anything that is derived from $\tilde{N}$ is independent of $T_1$. (More precisely, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tilde{N}$ is independent of $T_1$.) Since the 2nd inter-arrival time $T_2$ is the "first" arrival time for $\tilde{N}$ (hence is determined only by $\tilde{N}$), all of $T_1$, $T_2$, and $\tilde{\tilde{N}}$ will be mutually independent. This process will of course continue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarifications and the time you took for these explanations. Now it's clear for me :)

Comment: There should be more mathematicians like you, who really understands the technalities involved and can give a clear and rigorous explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume the definition 2 stated in the question.
Let times of occurrences be $0=T_0<T_1<T_2<\ldots$ and $N_t$ denote the number of occurrences in $(0, t].$

I use the fact that $$\{T_n\leq t\} \equiv\{N_t\geq n \}.$$
The distribution function of $ T_n $ is
\begin{eqnarray}
  F_{T_n}(t)&=& P[T_n\leq t]=P[N_t\geq n]=P[\cup_{j=n}^\infty \{N_t=j\}]
\\
  &=&\sum_{j=n}^{\infty}P[N_t=j], \qquad \text{as these events are disjoint} \\
  &=& \sum_{j=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{(\lambda t)^j}{j!}e^{-\lambda t}\label{eq:Erl}
 \end{eqnarray}
The probability density function is
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f_{T_n}(t)=\dfrac{dF_{T_n}(t)}{dt}&=&
  \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\sum_{j=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{( \lambda t)^{j-1}}{(j-1)!}-
  \lambda \sum_{j=n}^\infty \dfrac{(\lambda t)^j}{j!}e^{-\lambda t}\\
  &&\qquad \text{By letting } Q_j = \dfrac{(\lambda t)^j}{j!}\\
  &=& \lambda e^{-\lambda t}[Q_{n-1}+Q_{n}+Q_{n+1}+\ldots]\\
&& -\lambda[Q_{n}+Q_{n+1}+\ldots]\\
%  &=&\lambda[(Q_{n-1}-Q_n)+(Q_{n}-Q_{n+1})+(Q_{n+1}-Q_{n+2})+\ldots]\\
  &=&\lambda e^{-\lambda t} Q_{n-1}
 \end{eqnarray*}
The density of $T_n$ is given by $$
f_{T_n}(t)=\lambda \dfrac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-\lambda t}
,\qquad t\geq 0\quad n=1,2,\ldots$$
which is called the density of Erlang distribution of order $ n $
Hence the density of $T_1$ is   $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}, \ t\geq 0, $ which is an exponential density with parameter $\lambda. $
Consider the times $T_1$ and $T_2. $ By shifting the origin to $T_1 $, the time of second arrival occurs at $T_2-T_1. $ By the memoryless property of exponential distribution, $T_2-T_1$ is the time to the first occurrence of an arrival in (a new) process starting at $T_1 $ and that $T_2-T_1$ is independent of $T_1. $
Hence $T_2-T_1$ has identical distribution as that of $T_1. $
Proceeding this way, we can show that $T_k-T_{k-1}, k=3,4, \ldots$ are iid and have exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda. $